# iOS - failing to install app on non-jailbroken devices

Tags: ios, xcode, itunes, jailbreak

We have a bunch of iOS devices in our office, and I simply can't install any of my applications on 2 of them.

The devices on which I can't install are iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3 and iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0. Both are not jailbroken.

However, I can install just fine on similar devices with similar iOS versions which are jailbroken. We have another iPhone 4 with iOS 4.3 which is jailbroken and on which I manage to install just fine. Also successfully installed on a friend's jailbroken iPhone 5 with iOS 6.0.

This happens whether I'm deploying using TestFlight, iTunes or iFunBox.
The same thing happens with IPAs deployed using Marmalade

Things I've tried and didn't work:

- Building with both development and distribution profiles where applicable.
- Installing the provisioning profiles through iTunes.
- Installing the provisioning profiles through iPhone configuration Utility.
- Adding Entitlements.plist file with parameters as mentioned in similar posts.

none of the other solutions I've found online helped

This is the console log I get when trying to install from Testflight or iTunes:

```
May 12 16:58:44 unknown configd[25] <Debug>: CaptiveNetworkSupport:UIAllowedNotifyCallback:70 uiallowed: false
May 12 16:58:46 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 012c2000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from iTunes. Killing connection
May 12 16:58:46 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message
May 12 16:58:49 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message
May 12 16:58:49 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2ffb4000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from Xcode. Killing connection
May 12 16:58:50 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message
May 12 16:58:50 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 012c2000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from iPhone Configuration Utility. Killing connection
May 12 16:58:50 unknown installd[467] <Error>: 2ffa3000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620395
May 12 16:58:50 unknown installd[467] <Error>: 2ffa3000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.77Ng6N/foo_extracted/Payload/Mooniz.app
May 12 16:58:50 unknown installd[467] <Error>: 2ffa3000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
May 12 16:58:50 unknown installd[467] <Error>: 2ffa3000 handle_install: API failed
May 12 16:58:50 unknown com.apple.itunesstored[478] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
May 12 16:58:55 unknown lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2ffb4000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from iTunes. Killing connection
May 12 16:58:55 unknown com.apple.mobile.lockdown[17] <Notice>: Could not receive size of message
```

and this is the error I get when trying to install through iFunBox:

[image: iFunBox error]

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing once through through Xcode seems to have fixed the problem. After doing this, I can now install the app on the non jailbroken devices through other means (TestFlight, iFunBox), works just fine.

EDIT:

I found the real culprit, and it was the entitlements file after all. Since we're working on code which was written and released by our customer, and had to create our own bundle ID - some of the entitlements were missing from our profile, such as push notifications and iCloud. After adding them, installation went fine

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that these 2 devices are added to your provisioning profile?

It sounds exactly like the problem if UDID of devices weren't added to provisioning profile (or were added incorrect).